# Can't resolve method toLowercase()

Tags: android, floating-action-button

Creating fab share but it cant resolve method toLowerCase().
*dataLaundry is my model

```
 FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
 fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        //  Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        //       .setAction("Action", null).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/plain");
        String shareSubject = String.valueOf(dataLaundry.getNama());
        String shareBody = String.valueOf(dataLaundry.getAlamat());
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Laundrize - " + shareSubject);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareSubject + "\n" + shareBody + "\n\n" +
                "http:/maps.google.com/?q="
                + detail_alamat.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "+"));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share via"));
    }
});
```

Comment: What data type is detail_alamat ?

Comment: what  is detail_alamat..?

Comment: detail_alamat is idtext

Comment: It ll be better if you post your model class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this 
`detail_alamat.getText().toString().toLowerCase()`

because  toLowerCase() is method of java.lang.String it can not apply direct to your detail_alamat(idtext)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `toLowerCase()` method, you must to sure the `detail_alamat` variable's class extend `java.lang.String` or `java.lang.Character`.

In `java.lang.String` have two methods is `toLowerCase()` and `toLowerCase(Locale)`, in addition in `java.lang.Character` have two methods is `toLowerCase(int)` and `toLowerCase(char)` of the same.